# How to get and display AJAX post JSON response on web page using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax

I want to display JSON Response on the response on web page. Once user logged in it should show username on the web page. The AJAX post method  returns the JSON data. Please let me know to how to accept the json data and how to display it. at backend side I have following code.

This is my AJAX JSON data response

```
{
"userId": 79,
"userName": "ruchika@gmail.com",
"password": null,
"firstName": "Ruchika",
"lastName": "S",
"phoneNumber": "123456789",
"emailAddress": "ruchika@gmail.com",
"gender": "FEMALE",
"dateOfBirth": null,
"status": null,
"addressLine1": "1267 Vicente Dr",
"addressLine2": "Apt 155",
"state": "CA",
"city": "Sunnyvale",
 "zipCode": "94087"
 }
```

once user loogged in I want to show username, first name and last name on the webpage.

//this is my interface implementation file

```
 @Override
public User getByUserName(String userName) {
    User user = new User();
    String GET_USER_ID = "select user_id,first_name,last_name,user_name,email_address,phone_number,date_of_birth,gender,address_line1,address_line2,state,city,zipcode from user WHERE user_name=:userName";
    SqlParameterSource sqlParameter = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("userName", userName);
   // user  =(User)getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(GET_USER_ID, sqlParameter, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(User.class));

  //user data sending here in the JSON format

    return   getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(GET_USER_ID,sqlParameter, new ResultSetExtractor<User>() {
        @Override
        public User extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            User user = new User();
            while (resultSet.next())
            {

                    user.setUserId(resultSet.getLong("user_id"));
                    user.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
                    user.setLastName(resultSet.getString("last_name"));
                    user.setUserName(resultSet.getString("user_name"));
                    user.setEmailAddress(resultSet.getString("email_address"));
                    user.setPhoneNumber(resultSet.getString("phone_number"));
                    user.setDateOfBirth(resultSet.getDate("date_of_birth"));
                    user.setGender(Gender.valueOf(resultSet.getString("gender")));
                    user.setAddressLine1(resultSet.getString("address_line1"));
                    user.setAddressLine2(resultSet.getString("address_line2"));
                    user.setState(resultSet.getString("state"));
                    user.setCity(resultSet.getString("city"));
                    user.setZipCode(resultSet.getString("zipcode"));

            }
            return user;
        }
    });
   // return  user;
}
```

// this is my cotroller file

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
private LoginService loginService;
@Autowired
private UserService userService;



private boolean loggedInResult;

@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
User signIn(@RequestBody LoginRequestDto loginRequestDto,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    User user = null;
    String userName = loginRequestDto.getEmailAddress();

    String password = loginRequestDto.getPassword();

    loggedInResult = loginService.validateUser(userName, password);

    if (loggedInResult==true)
    {
        response.setStatus(200);

        return userService.get(userName);

    }
    else
    {
         response.sendError(403);
    }
    return user;
 }
}
```

// this is my javascript file

```
function Logincheck()
{

var u1 =document.getElementById("Username_loginfrm").value;
var p1=document.getElementById("Password_loginfrm").value;


var JSONObject= {
    emailAddress:u1,
    password:p1
};


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/shareonwheels/v1/login",
    data: JSON.stringify(JSONObject),
    contentType: "application/json",


    success: function (response) {
        alert("User has been login successfully.");

        loginSuccessRedirect();
    },
    error: function (response) {

        alert("Invalid User");

        loginFailRedirect();
        document.getElementsByName('Username_loginfrm').focus();

    }

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
$("#divid").html(response);

where response is a JavaScript variable containing response of the REST call.